# JavaScript: how can I put multiple items after my e.preventDefault?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use JavaScript to add and remove things, but I need to add multiple items here: http://prntscr.com/66j0vt

but I don't know how, because I don't have great knowledge with this language.

My code:

```
(function($) {
    $('#slideshow-pause-icon').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#slideshow').toggleClass('slideshow-pause');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I'd like to have something like this:

```
(function($) {
    $('#slideshow-pause-icon').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#slideshow, item2, item3, etc').toggleClass('slideshow-pause');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear what question you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried adding another line after your `toggleClass` call?  It will work just fine :-)

Comment: I can't, for example, use a comma to separate?

Comment: Your screen shot doesn't tell us what you're trying to accomplish.  In words, tell us what problem you are trying to solve.  What do you want to make your code do?  "Add multiple items" does not describe the problem.  Are you trying to run `.toggleClass()` on multiple objects?  If so, what is the selector for those other objects?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes, I want that. I'd like to have something like this: http://prntscr.com/66j4f9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you like to organise code you could do it a couple of ways.

jQuery/Javascript would happily allow either of the following:

```
(function($) {
    $('#slideshow-pause-icon').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Add as many elements and actions as you need e.g.
        $('.some-other-element').toggleClass('some-class');
        $('.some-other-element2').hide(400); 


        $('#slideshow').toggleClass('slideshow-pause');
    });


    $('#slideshow-play-icon').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#slideshow').removeClass('slideshow-pause');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Alternatively, if the elements are all doing the same you can use a comma separated list of element selectors

```
$('#id-element, .class-element, #id-element2').css({width:100px});
```

Documentation below.

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/